# Convert the distinct row values to column headers and summarizing the data using proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas

This is the sample data set.

[image]

Output

[image]

The required output,using proc SQL.Please have a look.

Comment: Please include anything you've tried so far. And also include your data as text, otherwise someone has to type it out to work with it. Please see the rules on how to ask a question [ask]

Comment: And what summarizes do you want?

Comment: Just wanted the sum of the marks for each student...i got the answer..thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use PROC SQL (as opposed to the default summary table PROCs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is one way to do :

```
select name, 
       sum(case when subject = 'math' then marks else 0 end) as group1,
       sum(case when subject <> 'math' then marks else 0 end) as group2
from table t
group by name;
```